# Creating a Reporting Template for Data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have some sales data in my database, and I'd like to show it to the user on a view controller. I have a template I wrote (it consists of 4 short paragraphs with some padding between each one).

Each paragraph contains 3-4 variables that need to be replaced with data from my database (I have a class that is bound to all of this data, so replacing the variables is trivial).

In addition to the above, I need to also conditionally hide several sentences within a paragraph, and finally conditionally hide one of the paragraphs alltogether.

Based on those 3 needs (replace variables, hide sentences, hide whole paragraphs) what is a smart strategy for achieving this? Is it going to be as messy as writing out all of the strings, and conditionally replacing them with ""'s? What about the fact I have to hide entire paragraphs? Does this mean I need to do programmatic constraints and/or set autolayout constraints to have less priority so it moves up?

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Mustache has an iOS port available called Swiftache!
Very happy about this and does exactly what I needed (conditional hides, variable replacement, etc).

https://github.com/BjornRuud/Swiftache